# How do I apostille an original NYC birth certificate without Letter of Exemplification?

Tags: immigration, new-york-state, notaries

I have an original long form New York City (Manhattan) Birth Certificate issued by NYC Department of Health in 2016 signed by Steven P Schwartz (City Registrar) needing apostille but missing a Letter of Exemplification

The [NY State website](https://www.dos.ny.gov/licensing/apostille.html) indicates they require Letter of Exemplification for all birth/death certificates but some [Apostille agency](https://www.foreigndocumentsexpress.com/apostille-blog-365/281-letter-of-exemplification-new-york-birth-certificate-tips) websites indicate they *can* apostille these certificates without exemplification, and others mentioned on chat they first "get" the exemplification and then submit for apostille; How do you "get" the exemplification? As far as I know the only way is re-ordering a new long-form certificate but they don't do that, so how do they obtain the exemplification?

I previously did send a non-exemplified NYC death certificate to the NY Department of State for apostille and they rejected it due to missing both the exemplification letter and county clerk's authentication (I hadn't bothered sending it to county clerk beforehand since I knew they can't sign non-exemplified certificates anyway, or can they?)

What is the special procedure/protocol to apostille this non-exemplified certificate?

Comment: Fair question. I don't have a ready answer to this technical issue.